# Why does `NOT IN` cte not work but `NOT IN` subquery works?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to solve the [Trips and Users SQL Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/trips-and-users/). If I'm reading this correctly, `NOT IN` cte does not work but `NOT IN` subquery does work. Why?

The following code works.

```
select request_at as Day, 
        cast(sum(iif(status like 'cancelled%', 1.0, 0.0))/count(status) as decimal(4,2)) as [Cancellation Rate]
from trips 
where (request_at between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-03')
        and client_id not in (SELECT USERS_ID FROM USERS WHERE BANNED='Yes')
        and driver_id not in (SELECT USERS_ID FROM USERS WHERE BANNED='Yes')
group by request_at
```

But the one below does not. I get the error message:

```
Runtime Error
[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'BANNED_USRS'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)
```

```
with 
banned_usrs as 
(select users_id from users where banned = 'Yes')

select request_at as Day, 
        cast(sum(iif(status like 'cancelled%', 1.0, 0.0))/count(status) as decimal(4,2)) as [Cancellation Rate]
from trips 
where (request_at between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-03')
        and client_id not in banned_usrs
        and driver_id not in banned_usrs
group by request_at
```

Comment: banned_usrs is a table in your cte.  If you try joining banne_usrs and then filtering once you join it would make sense.

Comment: As explained a CTE is a **virtual table** and not a sub-query. You cannot use format like "in table_name" since table might have multiple columns and there is no built-in syntax to check if a value is in all rows and all columns in the table. The syntax you should use is something like "`in (select column_Name From Table_Name)`"

Comment: Ohhhh... thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to explicitly select from the CTE:

```
with banned_usrs as (select users_id from users where banned = 'Yes')

select
    request_at as Day, 
    cast(sum(iif(status like 'cancelled%', 1.0, 0.0))/count(status) as decimal(4,2)) as [Cancellation Rate]
from trips 
where
    request_at between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-03' and
    client_id not in (select users_id from banned_usrs) and
    driver_id not in (select users_id from banned_usrs);
group by
    request_at;
```

A CTE by itself is just SQL code, and does not form a subquery unless you explicitly write it as such.